# Assign a function to other function with the change of the variable

Tags: functions, function-construction

I want to define a function that contains other functions but with other variables. Is it possible?

For example, I would like to do something like this:

```
A[x_, y_] = 2 x + y;
```

Now, some calculations on A, derivatives, and later:

```
B[a_, b_] = A[x,y]/.{x -> a Cos[b], y -> a Sin[b]}.
```

Comment: Use `:=` instead of `=` while defining the functions.

Comment: Thanks, in this case, it works. But, generally, is this possible, when I cannot use ```:=``` at the beginning? Generally, I am working with Eigensystems, so my first assignment, as I read, must be: ```A[x_,y_] = Eigenvalues[...][[1]]```;

Comment: You may directly define: `B[a_, b_] = A[ a Cos[b],  a Sin[b]]`

Comment: Please improve the question by including a minimal example so that you receive an applicable answer.

Comment: Along the lines of @DanielHuber, `B[f_][a_,b]:= f[a_,b_]` (e.g., `B[ArcTan][1,1]`

Comment: Thanks, it helped!